# how to import keychain

Tags: appium, keychain

Can someone explain how to import the the private development key?
According the Appium prerequisites for XCUITest we need to add the keychainPath / keychainPassword capabilities.
In order to do so I need to run 2 commands:
The security create-keychain command (which seems to work fine) & the security import MyPrivateKey.p12.
I guess that the second command should create the private development key file (The capabilites should point to it). 
The problem is that when I run the security import MyPrivateKey.p12 I get the following error:
"security: Error reading infile MyPrivateKey10.p12: No such file or directory"

Any help will be most appreciated!

=============================================================
ENV:Mac sierra latest version (10.12.2 )

The Appium prerequisites as published in the Appium community:

The commands that needs to be executed:
security create-keychain -p [keychain_password] MyKeychain.keychain
security import MyPrivateKey.p12 -t agg -k MyKeychain.keychain -P [p12_Password] -A

The full path to the keychain can then be sent to the Appium system using the keychainPath desired capability, and the password sent through the keychainPassword capability.